# Portable Python interpreter with pywin32

Tags: python

I have a python script that I wish to run on various different operating systems that do not already have python installed. To achieve this, I have tried simply copying the entire Python27 folder onto different computers, but that gives the error 'python27.dll not found' whenever I try to run it.

Also, my application now requires pywin32, which appears to require a proper installation rather than simply copying the modules and folders into Lib/site-packages.

One of the requirements is that this python script is completely portable onto systems without python already installed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: consider http://www.py2exe.org or http://portablepython.com

Comment: PortablePython appears to be precisely what I am looking for. Some parameters need to be changed when moving from one system to another, which are currently read from text file, so whatever tool I use to solve this must allow this text file to be edited.

Comment: Erm. I don't completely understand the last part of your comment. Notepad is installed in all Windows, and it provides basic functions to edit text files.

Comment: What I mean is, if my python project contains such files and then I use py32exe to turn them into windows executables, will I still be able to find and edit these files? I assume so, in which case py32exe suits my purposes better. Thanks for those.

Comment: This depends on your code. py2exe compiles python code, adds python interpreter and converts everything into a binary. If you edit your code, you should regenerate the binary. However, you could write the code so that it loads text file with parameters or discovers system characteristics during run time and chooses an execution path depending on what it has read or discovered.

Comment: I think my code is doing the latter; the code should never need to be edited, but takes different paths based on parameters being read from text file, or system variables.

Comment: Then it seems to me that both options are equally suitable. I personally would prefer Py2exe